# Syntax error or access violation: 1072 Key column 'kategori_id' doesn't exist in table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, migration

Is anyone have any idea about this prob?
I'm using Laravel 8, and I really had no idea which problem.
I already stucked at this for more than months.

Error Massage

\SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1072 Key column 'kategori_id' doesn't exist in table (SQL: alter table `produks` add constraint `produks_kategori_id_foreign` foreign key (`kategori_id`) references `kategoris` (`id`))

**Category Table**

```html
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateKategorisTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('kategoris', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('nama');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('kategoris');
    }
}
```

**Product Table**

```html
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateProduksTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('produks', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->char('kode',6)->unique();
            $table->string('nama');
            $table->foreign('kategori_id')->references('id')->on('kategoris');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('produks');
    }
}
```

**Category Factory**

```html
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Kategori;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

class KategoriFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = Kategori::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        $daftar_kategori = ["ABB","3M", "Autonics", "Supreme", "Omron"];

        return [
        'id' => $this->faker->numberBetween(1, \App\Models\Kategori::count()),
        'nama' => $this->faker->unique()->randomElement($daftar_kategori),
        ];
    }
}
```

**Product Factory**

```html
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Produk;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

class ProdukFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = Produk::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        $daftar_produk=["Inverter", "Rellay", "Lampu", "Push Button"];

        return [
            'kode'        => strtoupper($this->faker->unique()->bothify('??###')),
            'nama'        => $this->faker->randomElement($daftar_produk),
            'kategori_id' => $this->faker->numberBetween(1,
                            \App\Models\Kategori::count()),
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you add a foreign key in the Schema::create, you need to add the respective field first, like this:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('foreing_id');
```

And after that, transform it into a foreign key with the:

```
$table->foreign('foreign_id')->references('id')->on('foreign_table');
```

You miss the foreign field in the table products:

```
Schema::create('produks', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->char('kode',6)->unique();
            $table->string('nama');
add this--> $table->unsignedBigInteger('kategori_id');
            $table->foreign('kategori_id')->references('id')->on('kategoris');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Run your migrations again and the problem should dissapear.

Comment: Oh my, thanks a lot! I'm so glad, I didn't realize taking the wrong means from the book.

Comment: I'd like to add that you could replace the line that creates the column and the line that adds the foreign key with a single line that does both: `$table->foreign('kategori_id')->constrained();`

see: [link to laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints)

Comment: @chilly Aaah, is that so? okay, thanks for the info. :)